# Writing functional expression using numpy

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to write a function using numpy, so that I can take its derivative.[image]

I was trying something like this, but was not able to get it working

```
x = Symbol('x')
y = (np.e ** (x ** 2)) * np.sin(x - np.pi)

y.diff(x)
```

I get the following error on this

```
'Add' object has no attribute 'sin'
```

Comment: similarly `np.exp` does not work while `np.e` works

Comment: why do you mix numpy and sympy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the functions from `sympy`, not from `numpy`:

```
import sympy

x = sympy.Symbol('x')
y = (sympy.exp(x ** 2)) * sympy.sin(x - sympy.pi)
sympy.pprint(sympy.diff(y))
```

yields

```
       ⎛ 2⎞           ⎛ 2⎞       
       ⎝x ⎠           ⎝x ⎠       
- 2⋅x⋅ℯ    ⋅sin(x) - ℯ    ⋅cos(x)
```